# Different SDK for specific build

Tags: git, version-control

I have a web project. For every site I need different SDK. The final build for specific site of project shouldn't include SDK of other sites (due to a minimum build size is required). How can I handle that?

SDK should implement just several methods. I think it's unwise to create a new branch for each site and after each change to the main branch, commit to all the others. Perhaps there are some more elegant solutions.

My current solution is to have separate branch for each site with it's own SDK. Do changes in main branch and after each change, commit to all the branches.

Comment: Why are you committing SDKs to version control to begin with?

Comment: @StephenNewell I don't know how to handle several SDKs for different builds, except using multiple branches. Should I not use git for these purposes?

Comment: I've always used SDKs that are external my repositories, but I don't do web development.